# How can I prevent pest ingress past a flue thimble?

Tags: hvac

Twice now, rats have gotten into my attic and garage.  I've seen them travel from the water heater pipe into the attic from the gap you can see in the picture.

Unfortunately, the pipe has sagged away from he ceiling a few inches creating the hole.  I tried pushing on the pipe, but it won't budge.  That flared steel cover appears to be fixed to the pipe solidly and I can't slide it up.  I want to cover or fill that gap.

I was thinking of using expanding foam. Is this safe?  Would aluminum tape be a good alternative?

[image: gap]

Comment: cram the gap with steel wool; they hate chewing through that stuff (can you blame them?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Agreed with the comment by crip659 that the steel cover should move.

The material pictured here is called "double wall" or "B-vent". It has an air gap of about 1/4" between the inner wall, which is exposed to flue gasses and becomes quite hot, and the outer wall. This is intended to reduce the risk of fire should something combustible come into contact with the pipe, however, code does still require separation from combustibles (1 inch, I believe). So foam is not an appropriate material to fill the gap and in any case foam would not stop rodents.

Given that it does appear to have sagged I suggest you visually inspect the flue pipe along its full length to be certain it has not separated anywhere.

If the existing collar will not move you could buy a new one. Check your local home center or plumbing/heating supply stores for any of these:

Fire stop support (photo: supplyhouse.com)

[image: Fire stop support]

Storm collar (photo: homedepot.com)

[image: Storm collar]

Some styles are "snap-on" meaning they can be installed around the middle of a pipe rather than slid on from an end. If you can't easily find the snap-on style simply cut an ordinary part into two halves. Use sheet metal screws to attach them to the flue pipe. The cut line/gap between the halves will be small enough that it won't matter.

Comment: Ill try this weekend to see if I can get it to move while on a ladder.

Comment: @Keltari  Check for screws before trying to move.  Screws might have come loose enough for it to drop, or screw holes might be holding it.

Comment: Good idea - the rats could still be in the ceiling space, but that's its own problem.

Comment: Unbelievable   Last night, I went out onto my deck and at saw a rat jump from the roof of my house to the branches of a tree that has grown close.  I am going to get a ladder and  look at that cover more closely.  I will have to trim the tree too.

Comment: The flue thimble did not look to have anything holding it to the pipe,  So I started hitting it with a rubber mallet.  It was stuck hard, but I eventually got it to move.  It was really tight.  After a LOT of hammering, I got it fairly close to the ceiling.  I didnt want to get it flush, as I didnt want to bang the mallet into the drywall.  I havent seen the rat in the garage, but I heard something in the attic.  Well, one problem solved.